# Is it safe to leave a power bank connected all day to a 10 W solar panel (so with varying voltage and current)?

Tags: battery, photovoltaics, electronics

I have a 10W Solar panel with 5V USB output and a few power banks (the one I'm willing to risk for now is an older Li-ion one rated 3.7V/6000 mAh/22.2 Wh with microUSB-in 5V 1.9A max).

My question is whether is it safe to just plug this into the solar panel and leave it out for the entire day unattended, even when the sun isn't shining at all or is very weak. Would this damage either the solar panel or the power bank?

I have a USB multimeter connected right now and when the panel is in the shade I see the voltage drop to as low as 4.4-4.3V (at 0.02A) - it varies a bit when the clouds are passing by. I don't expect the battery to be charged at all in shade (even though the LEDs are blinking showing charging mode) but I am worried it might damage something. In direct sunlight the voltage is very stable at around 4.9V.

Comment: Most lithium battery using devices will have circuitry that makes them safe to a degree.  You do need to control the voltage fed to them as even that circuit has its limits.  Thankfully, your panel has a USB output which should have such already.  Just keep the batteries cool (not in direct sun, and not touching the hot panel) and you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll keep the powerbank covered and go for a test tomorrow all day.